# What does the pipe do in this AngularJS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="CartController">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <span>{{item.title}}</span>
          <input ng-model="item.quantity">
          <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
          <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
     </div>
     <div>Total: {{totalCart() | currency}}</div>
     <div>Discount: {{bill.discount | currency}}</div>
     <div>Subtotal: {{subtotal() | currency}}</div>
</div>
```

The `|` in the above code - what does it do?

Comment: Have a look at [Angular Filters](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pipe symbol (|) is used for applying filters in AngularJS.  A filter is a function that is invoked for handling model transformations.  Its basically just a global function that doesn't require registration of functions on a scope, and offers more convenient syntax to regular function calls.  The currency filter automatically formats a number in the current currency locale of the user.

[Video content unfortunately now behind paywall]
Check out this video for an example
http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-built-in-filters

Comment: I watched the video..I thought filters could only be used in conjunction with ng-repeat. This keeps reminding me angularjs is a powerful piece of software.

Comment: It's a paid video!

Comment: Hmmn thats too bad it was a free video originally